# Using watershader.js shader in aframe

Tags: three.js, shader, aframe, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am looking to understand how external shader files can be used inside a-frame without copying the shader code. I know that we can define custom shaders using aframe's registershader but is there a way to point the vertex and fragment shader code to an external URL?

For example, if I want to use the shader defined here - [Mr. Doob's water shader](https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/82bd697ef06acf5c4173775abe053d7a499a6722/examples/js/WaterShader.js) within a-frame, how can I do so without copying the shader code to my local file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script contains a global definition for

```
THREE.ShaderLib[ 'water' ]
```

if you include it in your html, you should be able to access it anywhere:

```
THREE.ShaderLib['water'].vertexShader // vertexShader
```

example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/068avuLr/).

---

To register a shader, you'd only have to properly define all uniforms in the schema:

```
AFRAME.registerShader('foo', {
  schema: {
    //all uniforms from the water shader lib
  },
  vertexShader: THREE.ShaderLib[ 'water' ].vertexShader,
  fragmentShader: THREE.ShaderLib[ 'water' ].fragmentShader
})
```

---

The script uses a `THREE.Mirror` which also needs to be included if you want to fully utilize the `water` ShaderLib.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, let me give this a try

Comment: @Niraj [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d356uLg7/8/) is an example of using a global ShaderLib object :)

Comment: hahaha..that's my code from another question that you modified to provide answer to this question. You are just AWESOME :-) :-)

Comment: @Niraj it seems to be a followup, and it was easy to re-use parts of the other anwser :)

Comment: Thank you again Piotr. You are amazing and I get to learn so much from you

Answer (score 0):

If you came from Google looking for a watershader for A-Frame: here is an additional [example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/dk-aframe-water-shader).